# Custom upload method dropzone and angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security, dropzone.js

I'm writing application (Java + Spring Boot with security on backend), Angularjs on front. I need to send file to backend with share token (security purpose). I have got csrf enabled on backend and interceptor in angular to use it when I create http request. But it doesn't work with ng-dropzone.

I added dropzone config:

```
$scope.logoDropzoneConfig = {
                parallelUploads: 1,
                maxFileSize: 30,
                url: '/api/companies/upload/logo',
            };
```

But I have got `type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied`.

It is possible to write custom method to send files instead of url in config?

Comment: Can you disable csrf only for /api/companies/upload/logo with spring-security when uploading with dropzone ? `http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/api/companies/upload/logo")`

Comment: @MGR my application have to be secure. I don't want to disable csrf for any service. It's not a solution.

Comment: Yes I just asked. We can talk about implementing CSRF with REST Services and not form submission but it's not the point here. How did you implemented CSRF token in your AngularJS app? (in meta tags? in a cookie ? [+ headers])

Comment: I post my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this problem this night.
In dropzone configuration I can pass headers so, i pass authorization token like below:

```
$scope.logoDropzoneConfig = {
                parallelUploads: 1,
                maxFileSize: 30,
                url: '/api/companies/upload/logo',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization' :AuthServerProvider.getToken()
                }
            };
```

Simple, isn't it ?:)